# How MySQL detects that an index is automatically generated?

Tags: mysql, foreign-key

MySQL creates an index for any foreign key column. Detecting those automatically created indexes is important for unattended migrations on servers.

For example if I manually create a new index on the same column, MySQL will silently drop the automatically created index, but won't drop it if I previously created it manually with the same name and format. Thus I end up with duplicate index and performance penalty for inserts.

So I need a **way to detect automatically created index** to not add it's drop to the migration script.

Note, I'm using Doctrine Migrations, which prepares the queries and later executes them. So I can't easily just see if the index is still there after adding the new index, because at the time of building the queries the add index query has not been executed yet.

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` may help in seeing what indexes exist.

Comment: It does, but it shows all indexes - both automatic and manually created :(